# Вложенный запрос вернул больше одного значения. Не знаю что делать

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
use Northwind;
--alter table Orders drop column OrderSum 

alter table Orders
--add OrderSum money


go
Alter procedure dbo.SetOrderSum
as
 update Orders
 set OrderSum=(
 Select UnitPrice from [Order Details] where Orders.OrderID=[Order Details].OrderID
 )
go
```

Ошибку показывает.
Hадо создать хранимую процедуру `dbo.SetOrderSum`, заполняющую данное поле значениями сумм заказов
хотел копировать данные из одной таблиц в другую
и еще надо добавить условие где discount =0 и discount >0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... (
  SELECT SUM([Order Details].UnitPrice - [Order Details].Discount) FROM [Order Details] 
  WHERE Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID
)
```

Comment: мне не надо сумма всех заказов, если грубо говоря надо просто копировать  данный из 1 таблиц в другую с некоторым  изменениями

Comment: @Nurym Вам надо сумма всех заказов с одинаковым `OrderID`

Comment: это понятно! Спасибо! но как добавить условие, Discount =0

Comment: @Nurym Откуда взялся `Discount`?

Comment: в таблице [Order Details] есть тип real. Надо dbo.SetOrderSum, заполняющую данное поле значениями сумм заказов (с учетом значения Discount!)

Comment: @Nurym Хм, ну добавьте `... where Orders.OrderID=[Order Details].OrderID and [Order Details].Discount = 0`

Comment: а как сделать например set and set. ну хочу сделать когда discount =0 и  discount >0

Comment: @Nurym Задайте все вопросы в вопросе.

Comment: хорошо задам все вопросы в вопросах

Comment: @Nurym Какое условие Вы хотите добавить в зависимости от значения `Discount`?

Comment: if discount >0 и  if discount =0

Comment: @Nurym Что Вы хотите делать в зависимости от значения `Discount`?

Comment: if Dicount>0: update Orders
 set OrderSum=(Select SUM(UnitPrice-(UnitPrice/(Discount*100))) from [Order Details]

Comment: if Dicount=0: update Orders
 set OrderSum=(Select SUM(UnitPrice)) from [Order Details]

Comment: @Nurym Странная формула - наверное, неправильная. Какой смысл поля `Discount`?

Comment: это вроде скидки

Comment: @Nurym Это секрет?

Comment: неа это скидки когда 0 нету,когда больше нуля ты делаешь из этого процент

Comment: я сделал такую формула потому что иногда пишет на ноль нельзя делить